How can I display only the current active cart in the commerce_cart_form view?
In my Drupal 10 Commerce 2 setup, the default "commerce_cart_form" view (on the /cart page) displays all carts associated with the user (or anonymous sessions). This includes draft or abandoned carts, which creates issues for the user experience.
I would like this view to display only the current cart, meaning the active cart tied to the current session or the latest cart created if the user logs into their account. However, the available configuration options in Views don't seem to offer a filter or relationship explicitly for this.
I’m looking for a solution that allows:

Restricting the results to only one active cart for the user or the current session.
Doing so, if possible, using the tools available within the Views interface.

If the solution requires custom code (e.g., a contextual filter, a twig or a hook), I’m open to suggestions.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Right now, the cart module renders a form for each cart provided to it in CartController::cartPage(). You'd need to override that controller to change the logic in that function or alter the page after it's been built, but before it's been rendered, to unset or hide the elements you don't want. That said, it's a reasonable feature request to provide more fine-grained control over this page in the settings.
Typically, I'd only expect to see multiple carts in a multi-store scenario, though you could also end up with multiple carts due to login activity due to a lack of cart consolidation.

Thank you, Ryan, for your guidance!
Following your suggestion, I created a custom controller to display the active cart, resolving the issue of multiple carts on the /cart page.
Additionally, I built a custom cart block to preserve the detailed cart information and styling.
This combination successfully replicated the original behavior while limiting the display to the active cart.
As you noted, I’ll open an issue in the Commerce Cart module to propose adding finer control over cart display settings.
I’m sorry that the space here doesn’t allow sharing the full solution.
